# How can I write this regular expression

Tags: regex, parsing, unix

I have a file structure like this

```
var1=12.785, blah blah variable2=45.654 blih blah F=0.454
var1=852.785, blah blah var2=45.654 // blih blah FGT=8738
var1=12.785, blah blah DGSTE=4583; blih blah TEST=473.6984
var1=12.785, blah blah var2=45.654 blih blah var3=48834
```

I would like a regex that would give me only the numbers after the `= sign

```
12.785,45.654,0.454
852.785,45.654,8738
12.785,4583,473.6984
12.785,45.654,48834
```

(Basically the variable=number structure holds)
Can you help on this ?
I am using GNU grep and sed (but have other tolls too)

Comment: http://regex101.com/ and http://debuggex.com are good for playing around and testing regexes, btw.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for your sample data: `var\d=(\d+\.\d+)`
The first subgroup contains the resulting number.

If your data is really as simple as you presented, you can even simplify this by using: `\d+\.\d+` which doesn't care about the `var` prefix, but it sure works fine on your input data.

Comment: Note that this doesn't match the integer cases (e.g., 8738) That could be fixed by replacing `(\d+.\d+)` with `((?:\d+\.)?\d+)`.

Comment: Sorry the `varN` was my mistake, `var` can be anything, also how to use it with sed or grep ?

Answer (score 0):

Try perl one liner as you are using from `unix`.

```
perl -lne 'print join(",", (m/=([\d.]+)/g));' input.txt
```

Using `m/=([\d.]+)/g` it is extracting all the number after `=`. assuming all the number will be in `xx.yy` format. Otherwise you have to change the regex `[\d.]+` into `\d+(\.\d+)?` with some boundary checking.

Answer (score 0):

To find all numbers following = you need a regex that looks like `=(\d*\.?\d+)`. 
You won't be able to get what you need with grep since it always returns the entire matching line. You'll have to use sed. You can find some helpful references:

- http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html